# Cambiar distancia entre intervalos eje Y Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estoy haciendo una función que represente el perfil de un árbol, a partir de una serie de datos que tengo a lo largo del tronco. Toma como datos de entrada un identificador (id) del árbol, una lista de la altura del árbol en cada punto (Z) y una distancia en forma de array (md).

```
 def ShowTreeProfile(id,Z,md):
    EjeX=Z
    EjeY=md[id,:]
    plt.scatter(EjeX,EjeY, c="g", alpha=1, marker=r'$\clubsuit$',label="Perfil del árbol")
    plt.xlabel("Altura de la sección")
    plt.ylabel("Distancia a la recta AB (m)")
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
    ShowTreeProfile (3,Z,md)
```

Mi problema es que la función hace lo que quiero, pero el gráfico resultante tiene una separación muy grande entre los valores de Y que desvirtúa la forma del perfil del árbol (tendría que ser más achatada).Para el árbol 3 por ejemplo me sale así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría hacer para que los valores del eje Y estuvieran más juntos manteniendo los del eje X? Gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes controlar el tamaño de tu gráfica y tus ejes con `plt.figure()`. Por ejemplo si tenemos el siguiente gráfico de puntos:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,10,11]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.scatter(x,y,marker='o')
plt.show()
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizando `plt.figure()` y su parámetro `figsize` puedo cambiar el tamaño del eje de abcisas o de ordenadas.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,10,11]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.figure(figsize=(2, 6))
plt.scatter(x,y,marker='o')
plt.show()
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer número de `plt.figure(figsize=(2, 6))` representa el eje de las `x` que lo he bajado bastante su tamaño, y el segundo representa el eje de las `y`. Juega con ellos hasta ajustar la forma del árbol como más te guste.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto! :)